# SQL Server 2019 PolyBase - CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE returns unsupported URI

Tags: sql-server, azure-blob-storage, polybase

I am trying to create an external data source in SQL Server to an Azure Storage account. I have created the database scoped credential, but when I execute the CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE command, I get this:

> Msg 105080, Level 16, State 1, Line 7

> 105080;CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE failed because the URI contains an unsupported path, fragment, user info, or query. Revise the URI and try again.

My create statement looks like this (obviously I have provided the correct container and account, just making it generic here for the sake of security):

```
CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE [Blob_CSV]
WITH
(
    LOCATION = N'abs://scottpolybasestorage.blob.core.windows.net/polybase', 
    CREDENTIAL = [BlobStorageCredential]
)
```

So I am not sure why I am getting the error. I have essentially followed the instructions here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/polybase/virtualize-csv?view=sql-server-ver16

Thanks in advance.

I have tried several iterations of the CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE statement, but according to teh documentation, what I have should work.

I have also tried:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE [Blob_CSV]
WITH
(
    LOCATION = 'abs://polybase@scottpolybasestorage.blob.core.windows.net/', 
    CREDENTIAL = [BlobStorageCredential]
)
```

But same error.

Answer (score 1):

When creating an external data source for Blob storage in SQL server using the code below:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE 
    AzureStorageCred
    WITH (
        LOCATION = N'abs://<containerName>@<storageACCountName>.blob.core.windows.net/',
        CREDENTIAL = AzureStorageCredential
    );
```

I encountered the same error as shown below:

[image]

I initially used SQL Server 2019, but after updating to [SQL Server 2022](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/install-windows/supported-version-and-edition-upgrades-2022?view=sql-server-ver16), I tried the same code to create an external data source. It executed successfully without any errors, as shown below:

[image]

Try using SQL Server 2022 version, and you should be able to create the data source.

Comment: HI Bhavani, I did get it to work with SQL Server 20022 no problems, so there must be an issue with SQL Server 2019. I do need to get it to work with 2019 so I may need to reach out to Microsoft.

Comment: Yes, There may issue with 2019 version.

Answer (score 0):

You need to read the documentation regarding SQL Server 2019: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/polybase/polybase-configure-azure-blob-storage?view=sql-server-ver15

It states the code must be as follows:

```
-- LOCATION:  Azure account storage account name and blob container name.  
-- CREDENTIAL: The database scoped credential created above.  
CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE AzureStorage with (  
      TYPE = HADOOP,
      LOCATION ='wasbs://<blob_container_name>@<azure_storage_account_name>.blob.core.windows.net',  
      CREDENTIAL = AzureStorageCredential  
);
```

For example, this works for me:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE [MyWASB] WITH (
  TYPE=HADOOP,
  LOCATION='wasb://myblob@pabechevb.blob.core.windows.net/',
  CREDENTIAL=[AzureStorageCredential])
```

Answer (score 0):

I was receiving the same error with the same SQL Server version (2019) and started working after just adding the TYPE.

```sql
CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE [Blob_CSV]
WITH
(
    LOCATION = 'abs://scottpolybasestorage.blob.core.windows.net/polybase', 
    CREDENTIAL = [BlobStorageCredential],
    TYPE = BLOB_STORAGE 
)
```